# Excel VBA save as text file without delimiter

Tags: vba, excel, delimiter, separator

I am trying to convert the output sheet from excel into text file using macro, but is it possible to convert a file without a delimiter? my existing code can only save as tab delimited but the system that I am uploading the text file detects the tab spaces as excess character.

here is my existing VBA code:

```
Sub SaveAsTXT()
Dim parts As Variant

parts = Split(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")
parts(UBound(parts)) = ".txt"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & _
    Join(parts, "."), FileFormat:=xlTextWindows, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need delimiter or a separator for distinct differentiate fields.

In approach below there is a code that you can choose you value separator optionally as you want.

Now `,` character as delimiter for default.

Notes about below code:

- **rngRange argument:** is the source range that you want to export as your report in *.txt file.
- **strSeparator:** is a your suitable delimiter can define here.

...

```
sub Report
    CsvExportRange rngRange:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("tblTaxRep"), _
        strFileName:="C:\" & ".txt", _
        strCharset:="UTF-8", strSeparator:=",", strRowEnd:=vbCrLf, NVC:=False
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub CsvExportRange(rngRange As Object, strFileName As String, strCharset, strSeparator As String, strRowEnd As String, NVC As Boolean) 'NVC: _
    Null Value Control (If cell contain Null value, suppose reached end of range), d: delimiter

    Dim rngRow As Range
    Dim objStream As Object
    Dim i, lngFR, lngLR As Long 'lngFR: First Row, lngLR: Last Row

    lngFR = rngRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows(1).row - rngRange.Rows(1).row + 1
    lngLR = rngRange.End(xlDown).row - rngRange.Rows(1).row + 1

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Type = 2
    objStream.Charset = strCharset
    objStream.Open

    For i = lngFR To lngLR
        If Not (rngRange.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden) Then
            If IIf(NVC, (Cells(i + rngRange.Rows(1).row - 1, _
                rngRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Columns(1).column).Value = vbNullString), False) Then Exit For
            objStream.WriteText CsvFormatRow(rngRange.Rows(i), strSeparator, strRowEnd)
        End If
    Next i

    objStream.SaveToFile strFileName, 2
    objStream.Close
End Sub 'CsvExportRange

Function CsvFormatRow(rngRow As Variant, strSeparator As String, strRowEnd As String) As String

    Dim arrCsvRow() As String

    ReDim arrCsvRow(rngRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1)
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim lngIndex As Long

    lngIndex = 0

    For Each rngCell In rngRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
        arrCsvRow(lngIndex) = CsvFormatString(rngCell.Value, strSeparator)
        lngIndex = lngIndex + 1
    Next rngCell

    CsvFormatRow = Join(arrCsvRow, strSeparator) & strRowEnd

End Function 'CsvFormatRow

Function CsvFormatString(strRaw, strSeparator As String) As String

    Dim boolNeedsDelimiting As Boolean

    Dim strDelimiter, strDelimiterEscaped As String

    strDelimiter = """"
    strDelimiterEscaped = strDelimiter & strDelimiter

    boolNeedsDelimiting = InStr(1, strRaw, strDelimiter) > 0 _
        Or InStr(1, strRaw, chr(10)) > 0 _
        Or InStr(1, strRaw, strSeparator) > 0

    CsvFormatString = strRaw

    If boolNeedsDelimiting Then
        CsvFormatString = strDelimiter & _
            Replace(strRaw, strDelimiter, strDelimiterEscaped) & _
            strDelimiter
    End If

End Function 'CsvFormatString
```

Comment: Sorry but I am new in VBA, just a question sir, should I put all of these code in a single module?

Comment: Yes, easy. just put all in a single module together.

Comment: Please set your suitable separator (delimiter)  as I write you above, before the code in notation. and set the export path. In first subroutine, you can set all parameters that you need, as export path and file name, your separator or delimiter character and ...

Comment: Yes I already did that `CsvExportRange rngRange:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("tblTaxRep"), _
        strFileName:="C:\Users\ivcosana\Documents\test" & ".txt", _
        strCharset:="UTF-8", strSeparator:="", strRowEnd:=vbCrLf, NVC:=False` I changed the  file path and is it possible to set the separator into NULL or blank?

Comment: What is the meaning NULL of Blank separator? Then how can u define the each fields value? Yes, you was do that. you have set the separator as null in setting this argument: `strSeparator:=""`. But here is a technical problem. after doing this and running the code, all of your fields data been join themselves, and you cant differentiate them.

Comment: nothing happens when I execute the module, is `rngRange argument` and the `strSeparator` are the only part that I need to be able to save it on my pc? I also change this part `rngRange:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("tblTaxRep")` can you tell me what does this part do? On my understanding, this part targets the sheet that I wanted to save into .txt file am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159212/discussion-between-amche-and-vince-osana).

Comment: Thanks for your help~! your code is 100% working now.